# "loading..." is displayed in some blocks of the site

Tags: discussion, design

Will someone explain the working of loading in Stack Overflow?

Every time I receive this loading in SO components:

[image: "loading..." examle]

Comment: Works on my machine, you got a downvote and an undownvote on that day, netting 0.  You probably have a proxy or firewall blocking the xhr traffic.